# Как сделать так, что бы INVISIBLE ImageView в первой активности, стал VISIBLE с помощью второй активности?

Tags: java, android

Помогите пожалуйста новичку!!!
Есть две активности.
В первой есть invisible ImageView и кнопка, нажимая на которую нас перебрасывает на вторую активность с пин-кодом, после введения корого нас перебрасывает обратно и наша  ImageView должна стать visible. Но она не становится видимой!!!

Вот чать кода:

MainActivity:

```
public static int MY = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mButtonOne = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    imageViewDoneOne = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.done_one);

    mButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (imageViewDoneOne.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PinActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, MY);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Что-то пошло не так...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });



 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MY){
        if (requestCode == RESULT_OK){
            int visi = data.getIntExtra("value", MY);
            if (imageViewDoneOne.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                imageViewDoneOne.setVisibility(visi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PinActivity:
(https://github.com/aritraroy/PinLockView)

```
public static final String TAG = "PinLockView";

private PinLockView mPinLockView;
private IndicatorDots mIndicatorDots;
private String pinCode = "1234";
private int visy = View.VISIBLE;

private PinLockListener mPinLockListener = new PinLockListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String pin) {
        Intent answer = new Intent();
        Log.d(TAG, "Pin complete: " + pin);
        if (pin.equals(pinCode)) {
            answer.putExtra("value", visy);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, answer);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Wrong pin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmpty() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Pin empty");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPinChange(int pinLength, String intermediatePin) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Pin changed, new length " + pinLength + " with intermediate pin " + intermediatePin);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pin);

    mPinLockView = (PinLockView) findViewById(R.id.pin_lock_view);
    mIndicatorDots = (IndicatorDots) findViewById(R.id.indicator_dots);


    mPinLockView.attachIndicatorDots(mIndicatorDots);
    mPinLockView.setPinLockListener(mPinLockListener);

    mPinLockView.setPinLength(4);
    mPinLockView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));

    mIndicatorDots.setIndicatorType(IndicatorDots.IndicatorType.FILL_WITH_ANIMATION);

}
```

Comment: Код выглядит рабочим. Но, наверное, вы задали вопрос т.к. он не работает. Если так - объясите что именно не работает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, во первых, спасибо Вам за внимание! Во вторых, я сам не понимаю.... Для проверки создпл текстовое поле, и оно меняется при таком коде, а имейдж ни в какую...(

Answer (score 2):

Вы опечатались.

```
if (requestCode == MY){
    if (requestCode == RESULT_OK){
```

Второй переменной должен быть `resultCode`

Comment: исправил, все равно не работает...

Comment: @ДенисКарбышев, ну... Выведите в логи значения всех использованных переменных - может станет ясно что не так. Код, в общем, правильный.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но спустя несколько дней попыток, так ничего и не вышло...(

Comment: @ДенисКарбышев, значит вы что-то не так делаете. Других ошибок в коде не вижу

Comment: Нашел ошибку: вместо int visi = data.getIntExtra("value", MY); надо int visi = data.getIntExtra("value", View.VISIBLE);